# How can I pass Google Form Responses (as variables to array) to HTML template for auto email alert?

Tags: javascript, html, google-forms, html-templates

My end goal is triggering an auto email to a client based on the Form users level (lvl)/priority selection. A level 3 should send the selected Form answers in an email template. (I assume I have the same issues for lvl 2 entries which are only for maintenance tracking)

I apologize if these may be a repeated question (I have very little coding experience, mostly VBA) but I have used the forum thoroughly to figure out most of this, and read [HTML SERVICES](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#code.gs), unfortunately I must be missing or reading over it, because I am having issues passing the Form answers (triggered by submitting) and evaluating the e.range to get an array string to pick from in the HTML template.

I end up with the following error on submission of a form.

" ReferenceError: returnData is not defined

at eval([unknown file]:10:70)

at eval([unknown file]:39:3)

at checkAlert(Code:34:29)

at onFormSubmit(Code:4:3) "

Here is my code:

code.gs

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log("[METHOD] onFormSubmit");
  
  checkAlert(e.range);
}

function checkAlert(range) {
  Logger.log("[METHOD] checkAlert");

  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var col = values[0];
  var lvl = col[8];
  
  // lvl 0 --> Do nothing
  
  if (lvl == "1" || "2") {
    
    var datetime = col[0]; // Timestamp
    var loc = col[1]; // Location
    var RAPID = col[2]; // Y/N needs attention
    var pumpspec = col[3]; 
    var pumpair = col[4]; 
    var counter = col[5]; 
    var comm = col[6]; // User comments
    var conc = col[7]; // User concerns
    
    var sup = "supemail@example.com"; // Field Manager, and Non-routine email
    
    var returnData = [datetime, loc, RAPID, pumpspec, pumpair, counter, comm, conc, lvl, sup]; 
    var html =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('2template');
    html.data = returnData;
    
    var emailContent = html.evaluate().getContent(); //HTML Output 
    
    var sub = "MAINTENANCE ALERT"

    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: sup,
      subject: sub,
      htmlBody: emailContent
    });   
  }
  
  if (lvl == "3") {
   
   var datetime = col[0]; // Timestamp
   var loc = col[1]; // Location
   var RAPID = col[2]; // YN needs attention
   var comm = col[6]; // User comments
   var conc = col[7]; // User concerns
   
   var client = "clientemail@example.com";
   var returnData = [datetime, loc, RAPID, comm, conc, client, lvl];  //For some reason causing getValues issues
   var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('3template');
  
   html.data = returnData ;
   var emailContent = html.evaluate().getContent();
  
   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: client,
     subject: "ALERT! Daily Inspections - RED FLAG",
     htmlBody: emailContent
     });
  }
  
}
```

3template.html

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  
   <h3> A technician has noted an immediate concerning issues:</h3><hr /> \
   <p> \
   <h1 style='line-height:90%'>Priority level <?= returnData[6] ?> - Location: <?= returnData[1] ?> <br /> \
   <span style='font-size:60%'> <?= returnData[0] ?> </span></h1> \ 
   <p><hr /> \
   <p> \
   <strong>ISSUE:</strong><br /> \
   <? returnData[4] ?> \
   </p><p> \
   <strong>ADDITIONAL INFO:</strong><br /> \
   <? returnData[3] ?> \
   </p><p> \
   <strong>FIELD MANAGER CONTACT INFO:</strong> \
   (123) 800-1234, supemail@example.com \
   </p>
    
  </body>
  <!-- var returnData = [0 datetime, 1 loc, 2 RAPID, 3 comm, 4 conc, 5 client, 6 lvl] -->
</html
```

I have tried logging 'e' when a form is submitted to see what I'm getting for the code to evaluate and it returns '[object][Object]'
It must be some concept error I don't understand. Your help is appreciated.

[Sample sheet for logging e](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1zFC457nD4kak1X41sPE7MLwO87puwnv6LMNErrkJdwg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: In your Google Apps Script side, `createTemplateFromFile('2template')` and `createTemplateFromFile('3template')` are used. But in your HTML side, it seems that the filename is `template3.html`. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike I apologize. That was a typo as I was replicating my code to be less specific to my company's info, clients, services. I edited the question. I should also note the code is on the Form and not the response Sheets. I assume this doesn't matter if it's utilizing 'e' to carry the response inputs. I'm considering just tweaking the code to work on sheets and just take the data from the newest input (lastrow).

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. About `I have tried logging 'e' when a form is submitted to see what I'm getting for the code to evaluate and it returns '[object][Object]' It must be some concept error I don't understand.`, if you had used `console.log(e)`, please use `JSON.stringify` like `console.log(JSON.stringify(e))` and test it again. By this, can you provide the sample value of `console.log(JSON.stringify(e))`? By this, I would like to confirm your issue.

Comment: I ran it with a standard form entry. Here is the whole stackdriver log:                             
Nov 22, 2020, 10:59:02 PM Info [METHOD] onFormSubmit
Nov 22, 2020, 10:59:03 PM Debug {"authMode":"FULL","response":{},"source":{},"triggerUid":"5419063"}
Nov 22, 2020, 10:59:03 PM Info [METHOD] checkAlert
Nov 22, 2020, 10:59:03 PM Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValues' of undefined
    at checkAlert(Code:12:22)
    at onFormSubmit(Code:6:3)

Comment: Thank you for replying. If `{"authMode":"FULL","response":{},"source":{},"triggerUid":"5419063"}` in your replying is the value of `console.log(JSON.stringify(e))`, it seems that `range` is not included. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about the detail of your settings for replicating your issue. So I cannot show you about the clear reason of your issue yet. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Yes I agree the {"auth... run is the console.log. Thanks for attempting though! Perhaps I will add another question specific to your query and find out why am I missing the range from the Form submission output. I'm always open to ideas.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, in your situation, when the OnSubmit trigger is reinstalled and test it again, what result will you obtain? If the submitted values are put to the Spreadsheet, I though that the event object `e` includes `range` object. If this was not the direction for resolving your issue, I apologize again.

Comment: @Tanaike I reinstalled the OnSumbit trigger and resulted in the same console log, and error for getValues. The responses are making it into the spreadsheet, so maybe I need to look into how the Google Form source code delivers it. I would replicate the my sheet, but it can easily be done with any  bogus short Q&A Form with my code above. I thought responses are sent in a string array of values, but maybe I'm going about it incorrectly.

Comment: I went a head and made an shared example Form with just logging e on submission, and still getting the same issues. So it's not isolated to my particular form. It must be a concept error, but yet I've seen others do the exact method successfully. The trigger  deployed from Head - From Form On Submit - Trigger by OnSubmit. See OP for the link

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, for example, as a test case, when new Google Form is prepared including a simple question and link to Spreadsheet, and then `console.log(JSON.stringify(e))` is used for `onFormSubmit(e)`, what result will you obtain? I'm worry that when Google Form is changed, the issue might be resolved. But this is my guess. I apologize for this.

Comment: The first run ended in the same issue. The second run results in no log at all.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot still replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. When I could replicate it, I would like to think of the solution. I apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon.